# Magento newsletter footer subscription success or error message Ajax popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento, newsletter

I am trying for the Ajax pop-up success/ failure message when any customer subscribes for newsletter. i have also followed this blogs http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/how-to-show-success-and-error-messages-in-an-alert-or-popup-39991.html

http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/948011695378/magento-newsletter-success-messages-in-js-prompt.html

applied as it is said but not worked. do anyone has step by step procedure ? I am new for magento

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: i have tried the first link for adding modalbox for the required result to be happens but it doesn’t worked....Please help.....

Comment: do anyone have it's entire code to share ???